# 2 different relations between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation:
There is a bunch of addresses from witch a client can choose a current one.

> ADDRESS(ID, CLIENT_ID, ...)
>
> CLIENT(ID, CURRENT_ADDRESS_ID, ...)

There is an obvious relation one-to-many

> ADDRESS[CLIENT_Id]>--->CLIENT[ID]

But there is also another one-to-one. I don't know  if it's correct.

> CLIENT[CURRENT_ADDRESS_ID]<--->ADDRESS[ID]

Should this be done by SQL relation, or later in code? (a sample SQL code would appreciated)

Comment: An address can be connected to many clients? And a Client to many Address'?

Comment: `ADDRESS[CLIENT_ID] >--->CLIENT[ID]` is not a one-to-many, it is a one -to-one. This would state that a given ADDRESS record can only belong to one CLIENT. Though a client may have many ADDRESS records that point to it.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore actually I meant one client has many addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client have to choose one of the addresses to set it as current, there's no need for the second relation, so you can do something like this

```
SELECT Client.ID ClientID, Address.ID AddressID, 
CASE WHEN Client.Current_Address_Id =  Address.ID THEN 'Current Address' ELSE '' END Current
FROM Client LEFT JOIN Address ON Client.ID = Address.Client_ID
```

You will get something like

```
ClientID | AddressID | Current
1          20          'Current Address'
1          35          
1          15          
2          18          'Current Address'
.
.
.
```

If you add the second condition

```
SELECT Client.ID ClientID, Address.ID AddressID, 
CASE WHEN Client.Current_Address_Id =  Address.ID THEN 'Current Address' ELSE '' END Current
FROM Client LEFT JOIN Address ON Client.ID = Address.Client_ID AND Client.Current-Address_ID = Addres.ID
```

You will get something like

```
ClientID | AddressID | Current
1          20          'Current Address'
2          18          'Current Address'
.
.
.
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

CLIENT(ID,...)

ADDRESS(ID,...)

CLIENT_ADDRESS(CLIENT_ID, ADDRESS_ID, IS_CURRENT_ADDRESS)

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation when you'd want to look into creating a third table to link clients and addresses.  It looks something like this:

Address (AddressID)

ClientAddress (AddressID, ClientID)

Client (ClientID)